# In Video Editing tab - any Audio FXs?

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor, audio

Is there any Add-on or Plug-in that would add Audio modifiers, like Reverb, Flange, Equalizer, etc. regular AFX stuffs?

Comment: No, there is not. And I myself would be thrilled if Blender would support VST3 or similar, but Blender is not an audio editor. And actually that's good, because audio works better in other programs, and Blender should focus on other things.

Answer (score 1):

An EQ is in the works: https://developer.blender.org/D14412

Alternatively, you can roundtrip strips or the full sequence in Audacity with this add-on: https://github.com/tin2tin/audacity_tools_for_blender

Answer (score -1):

Animation-Nodes for Blender Addon adds a bit of support for audio:

[Animation-Node-Addon-Docs](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/sound)